# Pass a NSString to UInt8[]

Tags: ios

i have this metod

```
- (int) write:(UInt8 *)data Length:(UInt32)length;
```

i want to pass a NSString to data with more character for example:

"Coca Cola"1*3H1R

Someone can help me?

Thank's

Comment: What do you mean 'with more character'?

Comment: "Coca Cola"1*3H1R  is my string that i have to pass

Comment: what do you want in return from this method?

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps..

```
NSString *someString = @"some text";
uint8_t buffer[100];
memcpy(buffer, [someString UTF8String], [someString length]+1);
```

If you have any questions just ask.

Comment: yes and if i want to loop more string i repeat your code in a for

Comment: Loop more strings? You will have to be a bit more specific with that. If you just use a for loop with the same code it will overwrite your string..